# Request to use Gmail Highlights and calendar entry cancellation for hotel reservations

Tags: cancellation, google-schemas

I am reaching out to you for more information on the implementation of Gmail Highlights and the handling of calendar entries for hotel reservation cancellations. My team and I are using structured data to provide improved email notifications to our customers and we have already received approval to use Gmail Highlights for reservation confirmations.

We are now planning to expand our offering to provide our customers with an optimal experience when cancelling their hotel reservations. In doing so, we want to ensure that the cancellation is not only displayed as a highlight in Gmail, but also that the corresponding calendar entries of our customers can be automatically updated or removed to avoid discrepancies.

In this context, we have the following question

Do we need to submit a separate approval request to use Gmail Highlights for hotel reservation cancellations, even if we are already approved for reservation confirmations?

Thank you for your support!